# GWT DatePicker Change In 2.5.1

Tags: java, gwt

## Background

In GWT *2.5.0* in the file: com.google.gwt.i18n.client.impl.cldr.DateTimeFormatInfoImpl_en defines `getFirstDayOfWeek` as:

```
@Override
public int firstDayOfTheWeek() {
    return 0;
}
```

This causes the Calendar to render as **SMTWTFS**

But in the update *GWT 2.5.1* this was changed to

```
@Override
public int firstDayOfTheWeek() {
   return 1;
}
```

Causes the calendar to render as **MTWTFSS**.

---

## The Question(s)

**Does anybody know why the default changed?**  I'm not really excited to go back and change all of my calendars!

**Does anybody know of a locale I can change to so the calendar renders as SMTWTFS?**  I would prefer not to create a subclass, override the `firstDayOfTheWeek()` and change all of the calendars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not prepared to test this solution but you might try using [GWT Deferred Binding](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred.html). If it works then the benefit is that you don't have to change a ton of code.

1: Create a new class and override the firstDayOfTheWeek() method.

```
public class CustomDateTimeFormatInfoImpl_en extends DateTimeFormatInfoImpl_en {

    @Override
    public int firstDayOfTheWeek() {
        // make Sunday my first day of the week
        return 0;
    }
}
```

2: Add a deferred binding directive in your gwt.xml module file.

```
<replace-with class="com.example.sample.CustomDateTimeFormatInfoImpl_en">
    <when-type-is class="com.google.gwt.i18n.client.impl.cldr.DateTimeFormatInfoImpl_en"/>
</replace-with>
```

Hope that helps or at least leads you in the right direction.